# count jsonb array with condition in postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have a postgres database where some column data are stored as follow:

| guest_composition | charging_age |
| --- | --- |
| [{"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1, "children_ages": [10, 5, 2, 0.1]}] | 3 |
| [{"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1, "children_ages": [2.5, 1, 4]}] | 3 |

i want to go over the children_ages array and to return the count of children that are above the age of 3. I am having a hard time to use the array data because it is returns as jsonb and not int array.

the first row should return 2 because there are 2 children above the age of 3. The second row should return 1 because there is 1 child above the age of 3.

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

`WITH reservation AS (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(reservations.guest_composition)->'children_ages' as children_ages, charging_age FROM reservations`

`SELECT (CASE WHEN (reservations.charging_age IS NOT NULL AND reservation.children_ages IS NOT NULL) THEN SUM( CASE WHEN (reservation.children_ages)::int[] >=(reservations.charging_age)::int THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END) as children_to_charge`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree. Unfortunately, I can change the data model.

Comment: `guest_composition` is an array itself. What do you want if that contains multiple elements? The ages for the first element? All ages across all elements? Also "the sum of the children above 3" would be 15 for the first row and 4 for the second. What is it 3 for both? Did you mean the _count_ of the children above 3?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name only the ages that are in the array of `children_ages` if there is more than one `children_ages` element, so i will want to sum them as well.
in that example, the first array should return 2 because there are 2 children above the age of 3. In the second array, it will return 1 because there is only one child above the age of 3.

Comment: The **top** level JSON is also an array, so it could e.g. be: `[{"x": 1}, {"y":2, "children_ages": [1,2,3]}, {"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1, "children_ages": [10, 5, 2, 0.1]}]`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are correct. It could.

Comment: So you want the count of all elements? Or just the first?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the count of all elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract an array of all child ages using a SQL JSON path function:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(r.guest_composition, '$[*].children_ages[*] ? (@ > 3)')
from reservations r;
```

The length of that array is then the count you are looking for:

```
select jsonb_array_length(jsonb_path_query_array(r.guest_composition, '$[*].children_ages[*] ? (@ > 3)'))
from reservations r;
```

It's unclear to me if `charging_age` is a column and could change in every row. If that is the case, you can pass a parameter to the JSON path function:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(
          r.guest_composition, '$[*].children_ages[*] ? (@ > $age)', 
          jsonb_build_object('age', charging_age)
       )
from reservations r;
```